# Read a txt file into a multi variable dimension array in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, readfile

I've the need of read a txt file that is structured in this way

```
0,2,P,B
1,3,K,W
4,6,N,B
etc.
```

Now I need to read in an array like arr[X][4]
The problem is that I don't know the number of lines inside this file.
In addition I'd need 2 integers and 2 char from it...

I think I can read it with this sample of code

```
ifstream f("file.txt");
while(f.good()) {
  getline(f, bu[a], ',');
}
```

obviusly this only shows you what I think I can use....but I'm open to any advice

thx in advance and sry for my eng

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a simple `struct` to represent a single line in the file and use a [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of those `struct`s. Using a `vector` avoids having to manage dynamic allocation explicitly and will grow as required.

For example:

```
struct my_line
{
    int first_number;
    int second_number;
    char first_char;
    char second_char;

    // Default copy constructor and assignment operator
    // are correct.
};

std::vector<my_line> lines_from_file;
```

Read the lines in full and then split them as the posted code would allow 5 comma separated fields on a line for example, when only 4 is expected:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(f, line))
{
    // Process 'line' and construct a new 'my_line' instance
    // if 'line' was in a valid format.
    struct my_line current_line;

    // There are several options for reading formatted text:
    //  - std::sscanf()
    //  - boost::split()
    //  - istringstream
    //
    if (4 == std::sscanf(line.c_str(),
                         "%d,%d,%c,%c",
                         &current_line.first_number,
                         &current_line.second_number,
                         &current_line.first_char,
                         &current_line.second_char))
    {
        // Append.
        lines_from_file.push_back(current_line);
    }

}
```

Comment: ty @hmjd this is exactly what I'm looking for.
I was thinking abuot struct but I didn't know how to integrate it into vectors^